# Using regex to validate password

Tags: java

This is my current code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String password = scan.nextLine();
        if (password.length() >= 10) {
            if (Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]\\d{2}", password)) {
                System.out.println("Password is valid");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Description**

Password rules:

- A password must have at least ten characters.
- A password consists of only letters and digits.
- A password must contain at least two digits

This is the code that I've been trying for validating the password but It doesn't print my output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following regex pattern to assert your requirements:

```
^(?!.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.{10,}).*\\d.*\\d.*$
```

This pattern says to:

```
^                   from the start of the password
(?!.*[^A-Za-z0-9])  look ahead and assert that we do NOT see any non letters or digits
(?=.{10,})          look ahead and assert that password length be 10 or longer
.*\\d.*\\d.*        then match any pattern so long as two digits be present
$                   end of the password
```

I would probably just directly use `String#matches` here:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String password = scan.nextLine();
if (password.matches("(?!.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.{10,}).*\\d.*\\d.*")) {
    System.out.println("Password is valid");
}
```

Note that we drop the `^` and `$` anchors from the regex pattern when using it with `String#matches` because this method implicitly applies the pattern to the entire string input.

Comment: Could you suggest to me where I can learn how to build the regex from scratch? I am interested in building the regex expression. Any useful resource that you would recommend

Comment: Tough question, as the general answer to your comment is that you just have to learn how to use regex.  I can suggest a good tutorial site: http://www.rexegg.com/ ... this is a good place to start.

Comment: Any best resource for testing the regex is correct or not that you would recommend. I'll use it in my learning.@Tim

Comment: [Try this great online regex testing tool](https://regex101.com/r/55ViW2/1).